# Can we make a short post here to showcase not so trivial formattings?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm regularly stuck with formatting when typing up questions or solutions. Having a brain like a holey pot I never can remember the necessary tags (the ones which are not in the simple/easy help.) Maybe we can create a single meta-site post showcasing some of the most typical examples for easier reference? (Or in some times only link to other SE posts which showcase it.)

Or is there a better place to do this?

> **Right now**, I'm **again** searching for the *cross-out of text*. I **know** it exists and is in some posts, just finding it...

Found it:  <strike>strike</strike> . ( `<strike> </strike>` )

Answer (score 2):

If you want a list of all HTML tags that you can use, [there's one right here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/180276).

This is linked from [the formatting help page](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help), which can be accessed via the question mark icon on every question or answer, so it shouldn't be too hard to find.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I *did* miss it on the formatting help page.  However, I'm also thinking of some example of "How do I keep tables within spoiler tags" etc.